# Is it safe to have static closures in structs?

Tags: swift, struct, closures, retain-cycle

I'm getting used to `structs` over `classes` in Swift, but have a concern about best practices if I'm possibly generating retain cycles due to closures not having `[unowned self]` or `[weak self]` ?   (which isn't allowed in a *struct* or *protocol*).  And the fact that I'm making all `static funcs`.

```
struct OrgAPIservice {

    static func getOrganizations(sinceSyncToken: ...
                                 completion:@escaping (_ orgsList: [Organization]?, _ error: AppError?) -> Void) {

        apiProvider.request(.getOrganizations(...)) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let response):

            case .failure(let error):
                completion (nil, getAppErrorFromMoya(with: error))
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You are not retaining any closures so there is no retain cycle. Nothing here to worry about. — But what is the point of the `static`?

Comment: The `static` is convenient versus always creating an object just to process some data.  eg.  I find `OrgAPIservice.getOrganizations(..)` simpler then  `OrgAPIservice().getOrganizations(..)`

Comment: A static func has no `self` (because there is no instance), so communication between of values between methods becomes impossible. Instances have independent instance properties which is safe and clear. The usual thing is to have a single instance of your "helper" struct as a property of your view controller class. You asked about best practice and I'm replying.

Comment: @matt - "so communication between of values between methods becomes impossible"? Surely static functions can use static properties in a similar way instance functions can use instance properties. It is one thing to argue it is not "best practice", but "impossible"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have `weak self` in your closure if the caller of the function is an object. The `self` refers to the object that provide the closure. It does not refer to the variable that owns the closure.

For example, if you have a class `MyClass`, then you can do

```
class MyClass {

    func callApi() {
        OrgAPIservice.getOrganizations {
            [weak self] in
            // ....
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct.  But internally `apiProvider.request(.getOrganizations(...)) { result in` embeds a closure.  Do `structs` treat closures differently then `classes`?

Comment: There is no difference. An escaping closure is just a variable which can capture references from the outside scopes, which means it has references to variables that are not defined in it. Only when the owner struct has a strong reference to an escaping closure, and the closure has a strong reference path to the struct will there be a retain cycle. @SebastianDwornik